# Limit of a sequence of bounded integrals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits

There is a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ that converges to the function $f$.

The corresponding integrals are bounded by the same constand constant $\int_E f_n(x)dx < C$.

**Question:**

1) How is it possible to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_E f_n(x)dx = \int_E f(x)<C$?

2) What are the conditions that we have to impose on $f_n$ functions to be able to prove 1)?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In which sense is the convergente $f_n\to f$? Pointwise?

Comment: @flytothesurface It would be great to understand the difference in proofs if the convergence $f_n\rightarrow f$ is pointwise or almost everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you impose enough conditions on $f_n$ so that $$\lim_{n}\int f_n(x)\ dx=\int f(x)\ dx$$

then the result follows from this proposition of sequences:

> If $a_n$ is a sequence that satisfies $a_n< C$ for all $n$, and $a_n\to a$, then $a\leq C$.

That will ocurr, for example, in these two cases:

- $f_n\to f$ a.e. (almost everywhere) and $f_n$ is a monotonous sequence (by Monotone convergence theorem).
- $f_n\to f$ a.e. and there is an integrable function $h$ so that $|f_n|<h$.

If you only assume $f_n\to f$ a.e., it is not true. For example:
$$f_n(x)=\frac{-1}{2n} I_{[-n,-n]}(x)$$
converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$, but
$\int f_n\ dx=-1\leq \frac{-1}{2}$, while $\int f\ dx=0$.